# Multi level header issue in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading an excel file with following structure -

[Input excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtEc.png)

and using the following code -

```
df = pd.read_excel("Myfile.xlsx", header=[0,1]) 
print(df.columns.ravel())
```

I expect the output should be like

```
[('Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Id') ('Name', 'First Name')
 ('Name', 'Middle name') ('Name', 'Last name') ('Unnamed: 1_level_0', 'Age')
 ('Unnamed: 2_level_0', 'Email') ('Unnamed: 3_level_0', 'Phone') ('Address', 'House NO')
 ('Address', 'Street') ('Address', 'City') ('Address', 'State')
 ('Address', 'PIN')]
```

But what I get is -

```
[('Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'Id') ('Name', 'First Name')
 ('Name', 'Middle name') ('Name', 'Last name') ('Name', 'Age')
 ('Name', 'Email') ('Name', 'Phone') ('Address', 'House NO')
 ('Address', 'Street') ('Address', 'City') ('Address', 'State')
 ('Address', 'PIN')]
```

Anyone has any clue why am I not getting the output as desired or is it what is desired? As the middle columns (Age, Email & Phone) are not part of Name (level 0 column), so what is being shown is incorrect. Any clue to resolve this?

Comment: why do you expect Age to be part of Name? At least in the screenshot of the excel, Age isn't part of Name. The same goes for Email and Phone.

Comment: unfortunately you have no way to fix this other than un-merging the cells in excel and filling them properly. Some may argue that you can use `ffill` and other methods but as you have legitimate `nan` columns this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to repro this. My guess is pandas is not considering whether the columns (Name, Address) are merged and assumes the columns represent the cells below, AND to the right.

I didn't see any reason provided in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) (see index_label).

And this makes sense, say you have a sheet that looks like this:

```
HEADER1        HEADER2
Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4,Val5,Val6
```

The first 3 Vals look like they fall under HEADER1. In your screenshot, they clearly do not. Since **Unnamed: 0_level_0** is sort of 'undefined,' they can get away with saying the labels are somewhat indeterminant, but they SHOULD handle the case of Merged cells, as in your screenshot, since that looks like a bug.

One other thing you could try is to put a blank ' ' space in the 'Unnamed' columns, to force them as being unlabeled. There may be other workarounds.